# Bar chart labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create a bar chart which has few columns and their label should show the name of that column.

Please see fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/akshayasharma/cdweowtq/3/

```
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [{y: 49.9}]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
             data: [{y: 83.6}]

        }]
    });
});
```

I want to label my first column as 'Tokyo' which is showing values for Tokyo and other as 'New York' which is showing values for 'New York'.

Comment: You can use dataLabel and format.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `dateLabels` and add a `name` to your data series: http://jsfiddle.net/cdweowtq/5/

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can set this up, and it depends on what, specifically, you mean by "labels".

I'll assume you mean the x axis labels in this case.

A simple way to accomplish this is to provide the category names to the x axis, like this:

```
xAxis: {
  crosshair: true,
  categories: ['Tokyo', 'New York']
}
```

And then simplify your series structure, like this:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Rainfall',
  data: [49.9, 83.6]
}]
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ks7g1bo9/2/

In order to maintain the color set up that you have in the example now, you could make the series somewhat more complex, like this:

```
 xAxis: {
   crosshair: true,
   type: 'category'
 },
 series: [{
   name: 'Rainfall',
   data: [{
     name: 'Tokyo',
     y: 49.9,
     color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
   }, {
     name: 'New York',
     y: 83.6,
     color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
   }]
 }]
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ks7g1bo9/1

These are just two of many ways to set this up, which way to go depends on what, specifically, you need.